# changing ntfs permissions for Windows internal usage, from linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, ntfs, acl, ntfs-3g

Troubleshooting an Windows 7 installation. One tactic is to increase permissions on files/directories ACL's (access control lists) for windows, from within windows, so all system data and drivers etc will be usable by Windows 7 OS, as they should be (long story about how they may have been changed).

Problem: can't use windows to do this, won't start properly.

Can I do this from linux. This is not about ntfs-3g allowing the mapping of existing permissions in windows to users in linux on, say, a linux partition in a dual system.

This is about changing the permissions on ntfs, from linux, so that, next time I boot windows, Windows will use those permissions.

I've read that windows is posix ACL compliant and linux can kind of use those. But I HAVEN't read that you can alter what windows itself will access within its own ntfs ACL's, from a linux system.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for an answer for bootable Linux, but you're goal may be reachable using  [BartPE bootable Live Windows](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/).  You can boot up into a Windows environment and make any changes you need to, and restart the Win 7 install to try again.

You may also be able to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to accomplish your goals using the chown and chmod commands from a Cygwin Bash shell.

Comment: It's been ages since I looked at BartPE, I don't remember for what reason. Thanks for the flashback.  n\It requires install CDs for windows, which I don't have. It provides the equivalent of taking your hard drive out and connecting it to a working windows system to operate on it with that functioning installation. I may just do that. But still curious about linux' possible ability to fix windows, "the windows way", all on its own.